# Zend Framework Form Element

Tags: html, css, zend-framework

I have this code:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn green pull-right">
            Potvrdi <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i>
            </button>
```

How can I make Zend_Form_Element_Button with these attributes? (including  tag, it is an icon that goes with the text "Potvrdi" as label on button)
I have done this so far:

```
$submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Button('submit');
    $submit ->setLabel('Potvrdi')
            ->setAttrib('type', 'submit')
            ->setAttrib('class', 'btn green pull-right');
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest solution is to disable escaping for the label and include the HTML code directly in the label:

```
$submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Button('submit');
    $submit ->setLabel('Potvrdi  <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i>')
            ->setAttrib('type', 'submit')
            ->setAttrib('class', 'btn green pull-right')
            ->setAttrib('escape', false);
```

However, If you plan to use this type of button often in your source code, you should consider writing your own `Zend_Form_Element` (e.g. `My_Form_Element_IconButton`) that takes care of adding these tags.